# Apple Passbook concerns about relevantDate and location

Tags: ios, passbook

I have successfully created an Apple Passbook for an event, but I am a bit worried about relevantDate and location as the relevantDate is `2017-11-07T22:42:39-05:00` on the Passbook, my concern is my event is on `Monday November 13 between 2pm - 8pm` will my Passbook with that relevantDate work on `Monday November 13 between 2pm - 8pm`? The concerning part is this `22:42:39-05:00` What does the -05:00 mean, is my passbook only good for 5 hours or until 5am on that day only? Meaning the passbook wont work on `Monday November 13th at 2pm - 8pm`?

My question about location is, currently I have 2 locations set, will my passbook not work outside of those locations?

Final question, are these fields required? If I don't set them will be good anytime, anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-05:00 means 10:42pm in a timezone 5 hours behind UTC.  E.g. The Eastern Standard Time Zone.

The times and locations determine when the pass will be shown on the lock screen.  For an event ticket, a lock screen notification will only trigger if the time and the location match.  If you don't set these fields, then the pass can still be used, but the user will have to open Wallet and find the pass manually.

The exact window of time matching is not specified by Apple, but it is around 2-3 hours before and after the time specified in the pass.

So, if I am in range of either of these locations between say 8:00pm on 7 November 2017 and 2:00am on 8 November 2017, the pass is likely to be showing on the users's lock screen.

Comment: So if I set my date to 2017-11-13T14:00:00-05:00 my PassCode will appear on the users lock screen at Monday November 13 2017 at 2pm - 7pm or around there or if I am near by the location?

Comment: No, it would display from around 12:00pm (2 hours before) to 4:00pm (2 hours after).  The -05:00 tells Wallet to use 2:00pm in New York as the reference time, as opposed to 2:00pm in Paris (+01:00), San Francisco (-08:00) or Hong Kong (+08:00)

Comment: okay so `16:00:00` = 2:00pm to 6:00pm ? Can I customize the Near By Message or no?

Comment: Correct - the message can be set in the locations dictionary in pass.json. `"locations":[{"latitude":-21.805149,"longitude":-49.089977,"relevantText":"This text will show on the lock screen"}]`

Comment: Hey, Thanks Man!

Comment: Hi, on lock screen, I was unable to set the application icon. a black logo always comes out. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Don't use a transparent PNG.  Always set the background colour otherwise, you may end up with balck on black. Wallet caches icons, so delete all passes with your old icon before adding one with your new icon.